# file_get_contents() not working in yahoo host

Tags: php

i an displaying live stock quotes using `$data = file_get_contents("http://quote.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=$symbol&f=sl1d1t1c1ohgv&e=.csv");` but i am using yahoo host. it doesnot allowing allow_url to change even not uploading .htaccess file. so how can i display live stock quotes in my webste.

Comment: - what errors do you exactly get ? please put some code examples -it might been redirected , check headers .

Comment: getting this error
Warning: file_get_contents(): URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration in /index.php on line 168

Warning: file_get_contents(http://quote.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=AAPL&f=sl1d1t1c1ohgv&e=.csv): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in /index.php on line 168
#

Comment: They probably disabled `allow_url_fopen` in their php.ini. Good for them (it's really insecure).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php 
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://quote.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=$symbol&f=sl1d1t1c1ohgv&e=.csv');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec();
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Use cURL :) Much better!

Comment: i used this code but i am getting this error.HTTP/1.1 301 Redirect Date: Mon, 17 Jan 2011 11:49:28 GMT Connection: close Server: YTS/1.17.23.1 Cache-Control: no-store Content-Type: text/html Content-Language: en Location: http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=AAPL&f=sl1d1t1c1ohgv&e=.csv Content-Length: 257 "http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=AAPL&f=sl1d1t1c1ohgv&e=.csv".                        getting this error

Comment: 301 usually meanst you need to also set CURLOPT FOLLOWREDIRECT iirc ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use cURL as mentioned by the other responses, but if they have disabled URL file-access I doubt cURL would work either.

The only way you could do it is have your PHP script hosted somewhere else that allows this and use Javascript to fetch the data using AJAX.

Comment: sorry i didnt understood. please explain .